# Use ?. operator in principal id checks for security

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, spring-annotations

I have the below code change.

```
-    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated() and #employee.id == principal.id")
+    @PreAuthorize("#employee.id == principal?.id")
```

Here the developer makes changes as shown above. Are the two security checks same? So if I make sure that the principal exists and is not null, it is the same as making sure that the user is authenticated and the user is not anonymous?

I found the below from the spring security documentation

### Table 15.1. Common built-in expressions

### Expression Description

```
hasRole([role]) Returns true if the current principal has the specified role.
hasAnyRole([role1,role2])   Returns true if the current principal has any of the supplied roles (given as a comma-separated list of strings)
principal   Allows direct access to the principal object representing the current user
authentication  Allows direct access to the current Authentication object obtained from the SecurityContext
permitAll   Always evaluates to true
denyAll Always evaluates to false
isAnonymous()   Returns true if the current principal is an anonymous user
isRememberMe()  Returns true if the current principal is a remember-me user
isAuthenticated()   Returns true if the user is not anonymous
isFullyAuthenticated()  Returns true if the user is not an anonymous or a remember-me user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this would validate that there is a principal object available. As per the documentation - Authentication is a Principal.

```
    public interface Authentication extends Principal, Serializable {}
```

Comment: So does that mean that if I am checking for the existence of principal, I don't need to check for authentication because the existence of principal implies authentication implicitly ?